# How do i get openOrCreateDatabase in arrayadapter

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to access my database inside my arrayadapter to remove an item from the list. But the code can not resolve the openOrCreateDatabase method or the symbol MODE_PRIVATE.

my code:

```
public class workoutListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public workoutListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.workout_row_layout, values);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final LayoutInflater theInflater =  LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    final View theView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.workout_row_layout,
            parent, false);

    //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
    ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton)theView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);

    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            removeWorkout(id);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


    return theView;
}

private void removeWorkout(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase workoutDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Database.sqlite", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    workoutDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM table WHERE id = " + id + ";");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access **MODE_PRIVATE** and **openOrCreateDatabase** you will have to use context of activity.

Comment: how do i acces it in my method?

Comment: SQLiteDatabase workoutDB = context.openOrCreateDatabase("Database.sqlite", context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

Comment: You are receiving context in your constructor,

public workoutListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.workout_row_layout, values);
}

So create a global variable for context so it is accessible in your whole class.

Comment: No I can't get the code right. not quite sure how to do this. It won't accept any new lines in my  workoutListViewAdapter constructor

Comment: `public workoutListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.workout_row_layout, values);
this.mContext = context;
}`

Declare mContext in adapter class globally.

Comment: Ok so that worked, didn't realise u can set the context BEFORE the super call. Thanks alot!

Comment: Great. You can always accept my answer if you agree with answer.